# What method to use for escaping all escapable characters

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have trouble with my database: I need to prepare my insert commands for any kind of escape characters like `" ' ?  /`. I could encode them using the key that I have written, but since this takes a small portion of time to calculate and insert, I'd like to know if there is any kind of insert that doesn't collide?

I'm currently using this

```
String selectSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM "+postid+" WHERE name="+"'"+name+"'";

ResultSet tableExistance = null;
tableExistance = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL2).executeQuery(selectSQL2);
```

Comment: appearantly ur right, put it as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` will handle the escaping of characters (except for reserved word escaping) but you will need to use the correct version of [`executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery--)

```
PreparedStatement statement = 
                conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name=?");
statement.setString(1, "Foo");
ResultSet tableExistance = statement.executeQuery();
```